# Toggle between charts using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have requirement where in need to switch between different charts using options from drop down or radio button. The chart i click must overwrite previous chart and show different chart with same data.

I have simulated similar kind of code but finding it difficult to overwrite with previous.
Here is the jsfiddle reference  in my comments:

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Sohan

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sohan/YtdE8/11/

Comment: I made this worked buy some cosmetic changes.
Thank you ,this may help anyone in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use update() function, which allows to update type of serie, so data will be the same, but line can be replaced with column or other types.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()

EDIT:

```
$.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){
                serie.update({
                    type:'column'
                });
            });
```

Couple of series:
http://jsfiddle.net/GGvmM

Comment: This is much better.. Thanks

Comment: I have one problem here,when i have more than one series. In that case information is messed up. Do you any clue?

Comment: You can use loop, for each serie and change type. Global type for chart should be available in the nearest future. See my edit

Comment: Hi anyway I can switch the chart type back and forth instead?